# A very large square matrix powered by 2

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, optimization, memory-management

I have a very large square matrix of order around 570,000 x 570,000 and I want to power it by 2.

The data is in json format casting to associative array in array (dict inside dict in python) form

Let's say I want to represent this matrix:

```
[ [0, 0, 0],
  [1, 0, 5],
  [2, 0, 0] ]
```

In json it's stored like:

```
{"3": {"1": 2}, "2": {"1": 1, "3": 5}}
```

Which for example `"3": {"1": 2}` means the number in 3rd row and 1st column is 2.

I want the output to be the same as json, but powered by 2 (matrix multiplication)

The programming language isn't important. I want to calculate it the fastest way (less than 2 days, if possible)

So I tried to use Numpy in python (`numpy.linalg.matrix_power`), but it seems that it doesn't work with my nested unsorted dict format.

I wrote a simple python code to do that but I estimated that it would take 18 days to accomplish:

```
jsonFileName = "file.json"
def matrix_power(arr):
    result = {}
    for x1,subarray in arr.items():
        print("doing item:",x1)
        for y1,value1 in subarray.items():
            for x2,subarray2 in arr.items():
                if(y1 != x2):
                    continue
                for y2,value2 in subarray2.items():
                    partSum = value1 * value2
                    result[x1][y2] = result.setdefault(x1,{}).setdefault(y2,0) + partSum

    return result

import json
with open(jsonFileName, 'r') as reader: 
    jsonFile = reader.read()
    print("reading is succesful")
    jsonArr = json.loads(jsonFile)
    print("matrix is in array form")
    matrix = matrix_power(jsonArr)
    print("Well Done! matrix is powered by 2 now")
    output = json.dumps(matrix)
    print("result is in json format")
    writer = open("output.json", 'w+')
    writer.write(output)
    writer.close()
print("Task is done! you can close this window now")
```

Here, X1,Y1 is the row and col of the first matrix which then is multiplied by the corresponding element of the second matrix (X2,Y2).

Comment: If it isn't a sparse matrix, it would take something like 2.6 terrabytes to hold the matrix in memory (or perhaps even more with your json representation). Do you have that much RAM? If it is a sparse matrix, look into a sparse matrix library, but then you could run into the issue that the power of a sparse matrix need not be sparse.

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks. yes sparse matrix library did the work! now I have to somehow translate csr_matrix back to json serializable

Comment: Then consider accepting Francisco Couzo's answer since they were able to provide the relevant details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Numpy is not the problem, you need to input it on a format that numpy can understand, but since your matrix is really big, it probably won't fit in memory, so it's probably a good idea to use a sparse matrix (`scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`):

```
m = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix((
    [v for row in data.values() for v in row.values()], (
        [int(row_n) for row_n, row in data.items() for v in row],
        [int(column) for row in data.values() for column in row]
    )
))
```

Then it's just a matter of doing:

```
m**2
```

Comment: WOW! that did it in 9 seconds! thanks, now all I should do is to change csr_matrix format to a json serializable format

Comment: Be careful, `m**2` just squares every element.  If you want to matrix power, you need `m @ m`.  That . . will not take 9 seconds.

Comment: @DanielF `m` is a matrix, not an array, so `m**2` will work as expected

Answer (score 1):

> now I have to somehow translate csr_matrix back to json serializable

Here's one way to do that, using the attributes **data**, **indices**, **indptr** - `m` is the *csr_matrix*:

```
d = {}
end = m.indptr[0]
for row in range(m.shape[0]):
  start = end
  end = m.indptr[row+1]
  if end > start:       # if row not empty
    d.update({str(1+row): dict(zip([str(1+i) for i in m.indices[start:end]], m.data[start:end]))})
output = json.dumps(d, default=int)
```

Comment: I don't know how it can hold csr_matrix format but not in dictionary. d.update gives MemoryError after some time

Comment: @MMFire - Hmm - is perhaps still the variable holding the original dictionary alive and occupies memory? If so, you could delete it or reuse it for the result.

Comment: if you mean `jsonArr`, i set it to `""` but i think it would only take 30MB as the input filesize is... i found a function in numpy which was useful... `np.savez` almost did the work... the only problem is that it outputs as .npz format, not json

Comment: @MMFire - You could check for other defined, possibly unneeded variables and their sizes with `import sys` and `for key, val in vars().copy().items(): print(sys.getsizeof(val), key)` before the update loop.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how it can hold csr_matrix format but not in dictionary. d.update gives MemoryError after some time

Here's a variant which doesn't construct the whole output dictionary and JSON string in memory, but prints the individual rows directly to the output file; this should need considerably less memory.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
…
import json
import sys
sys.stdout = open("output.json", 'w')
delim = '{'
end = m.indptr[0]
for row in range(m.shape[0]):
  start = end
  end = m.indptr[row+1]
  if end > start:       # if row not empty
    print(delim, '"'+str(1+row)+'":',
          json.dumps(dict(zip([str(1+i) for i in m.indices[start:end]], m.data[start:end])), default=int)
         )
    delim = ','
print('}')
```